# Expanding thumbnails on SharePoint via Microsoft graph

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api

**Trying to get thumbnails on SharePoint search**

This returns the correct search results:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{SHAREPOINT_DRIVE_ID}/root/search(q='{QUERY}')
```

But this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{SHAREPOINT_DRIVE_ID}/root/search(q='{QUERY}')?expand=thumbnails(select=large)
```

Returns:

```
{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UnknownError","message":"Unknown Error","innerError":{"request-id":"69bc5cdf-0f4a-4d60-9c3c-513983dd8e0b","date":"2016-08-04T17:50:11"}}},"status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error"}
```

The [documentation](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_search) explicitly states: `This method supports the OData Query Parameters to help customize the response.`

Answer (score 2):

Based on the test, the `expand` works well for the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root?expand=thumbnails(select=large)`.

It seems that the Microsoft Graph search item API doesn't support to expand thumbnails.

If you want this feature, you can submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: The documentation explicitly states: `This method supports the OData Query Parameters to help customize the response.` : 
http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_search

Comment: Search doesn't currently allow you to expand the thumbnails collection. Seems like a miss though, since the thumbnails make it easier to show the search results to the user.You can still use the other OData query parameters, like $select to shape the response. I'll log a bug to update the documentation to be more clear.